# LINQ select problems

Tags: linq

```
from item in db.Items
join ci in db.ChainStoreItems on item.ItemId equals ci.ItemId
where ci.ChainStoreId == 2
select item
```

The problem is as follows: `Item` has a set of `ChainStoreItems`. I want to write a query which returns an `Item` which doesn't have a set of `ChainStoreItems` it should hold only the one specific `ChainStoreItem` for the selected `ChainStore`.

So I only want do have the additional columns in item which came from `ChainStoreItem` however this is possible

That's a SQL statement which would do what I want

```
SELECT        
    ChainStoreItems.ChainStoreId, ChainStoreItems.ItemId, 
    Item.ProcStatus, Item.Del, Item.LastUpdate, 
    ChainStoreItems.AllowToReturn, 
    ChainStoreItems.AllowToSale
FROM
    ChainStoreItems 
INNER JOIN
    Item ON ChainStoreItems.ItemId = Item.ItemId
WHERE
    (ChainStoreItems.ChainStoreId = 140)
```

Comment: Ok so ONE orderitem has ONE item and ONE item has MANY chainstoreitems? and you want to query for an orderitem and it's associated item details?

Comment: neraly ONE orderitem has One item and ONE item has MANY chainstoreitems but i have a special chainstore so i am not intrested in ALL chainstoreitems only in a specific one

Comment: Im still a bit confused as to what you want to do. The impression I get is that you just want to search for a specific item? If so then what are your search terms? i.e. are you searching by ID etc? Why don't you just join the orderitem and the item tables and do a where clause to find the specific item?

Comment: give me a second i will shrink down the select to the ecentialproblem

Comment: okay its changed now may u now can see the problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are getting at!?

```
var result = from item in db.Items
                     join ci in db.ChainStoreItems 
                     on item.ItemId equals ci.ItemId 
                     where ci.ChainStoreId == 2                      
                     into itemci // note grouping        
                     select new
                     {
                             //Whatever you want in here
                     };
        return result;
```

Sorry i'm still not quite seeing what exactly it is you want to achieve. As far as i'm aware it's simply a matter of creating a join and pulling back the appropriate details

Answer (score 1):

Does ChainStoreItem have an Item property?

In which case, is it just:

```
from csi in ChainStoreItems
where csi.ChainStoreId == 140
select new { ChainStoreItem = csi, Item = csi.Item }
```

... or have I misunderstood?